# Overflow hidden not working with relative container and absolute element solution

Tags: html, css, overflow

I am having a little problem hiding a span inside a div. I have looked into stackoverflow for related questions and i came to a conclusion that the element to be hidden should be absolutely positioned and the container containing the element should be relatively positioned. I have implemented the solution but it still isn't working.

HTML:

```
<div class="column1">
    <div class="menuitem">
        <div class="leftmenuitem"><span class="title">MEAT SHAWARMA</span><span class="dots"></span>

        </div>
        <div class="rightmenuitem">$3.99</div>
        <div class="leftmenuitem"><span class="title">CHICKEN SHAWARMA</span><span class="dots"></span>

        </div>
        <div class="rightmenuitem">$3.99</div>
    </div>
    <div class="menuitem">
        <div class="leftmenuitem"><span class="title">SOJUK</span><span class="dots"></span></span>
        </div>
        <div class="rightmenuitem">$4.49</div>
        <div class="leftmenuitem"><span class="title">SAUSAGE</span><span class="dots"></span></span>
        </div>
        <div class="rightmenuitem">$4.49</div>
        <div class="leftmenuitem"><span class="title">BASTERMA</span><span class="dots"></span></span>
        </div>
        <div class="rightmenuitem">$4.49</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.column1 {

    float:left;

    width:50%;

}

.column2 {

    float:left;

    width:50%;

}

.menuitem {

    margin-bottom:10px;

    margin-top: 30px;

    position:relative;

    overflow:hidden;

}

.leftmenuitem {

    width:90%;

    float:left;

    position: relative;

}

.dots {

    position: absolute;

    bottom: 5px;

    left: 0;

    right: 0;

    z-index: 1;

    margin: 0;

    border: 0;

    height: 3px;

    display: block;

    background-image: radial-gradient(circle closest-side, #b3b3b3 99%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 1%);

    background-position: bottom;

    background-size: 6px 3px;

    background-repeat: repeat-x;

    overflow:hidden;

}

.title {

    position: relative;

    z-index: 5;

}

.rightmenuitem {

    width:10%;

    float:right;

    text-align:right;

    position: relative;

}
```

JSSFIDDLE:

http://jsfiddle.net/oct9jydv/

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding `background-color:#fff;` to `.title`